# Phonegap/cordova cli not working when i add plugins

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am using the phonegap cli to compile my apps.. the demo apps is complied fine. but as soon as i add a plugin it shows the following error.

i am trying to install the cordova file and camera plugins no 3rd party plugins.

when i add the plugin i get the following error:

```
C:\wamp\www\PhoneGap_WORKING\test4>phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.file" via plugin registry

npm

http

GET
 http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.file

npm

http

304
 http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.file

Installing "org.apache.cordova.file" for android

Failed to install 'org.apache.cordova.file':Error: ENOENT, no such file or direc
tory 'C:\wamp\www\PhoneGap_WORKING\test4\plugins\org.apache.cordova.file\www\Dir
ectoryEntry.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:140:36
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:120:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.handlePrepare (C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
honegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:81:
24)
    at C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:599:21
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\no
de_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
```

when i build the app i get the following:

```
 [phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\wamp\www\PhoneGap_WORKING\test4\plu
gins\org.apache.cordova.camera\www\CameraConstants.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:140:36
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:120:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.handlePrepare (C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
honegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:81:
24)
    at C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:101:25
    at Array.map (native)
    at C:\Users\prantik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:65:40
```

what seems to be the problem???

Comment: The plugin installation is not going through. Can you try creating a separate cordova app in a different folder and install a plugin there?

Comment: tried it...it didn't work with it as well

Comment: What is the version of cordova?

Comment: cordova is 4.1.2 and phonegap is 4.1.2-0.22.10

Answer (score 1):

try install `https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file` instead `org.apache.cordova.file`.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file
```